# Hotspot in Ubuntu 18.04 via external wificard (iBaton)

Tags: 18.04, hot-spot, lsusb, lspci

I am using laptop with Ubuntu 18.04, and using two WiFi card

1. PCI wifi card

   ```
   $ lspci | grep -i Network
   03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
   ```
2. external wifi card(USB)

   ```
   $ lsusb
   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:5776 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3121 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
   Bus 003 Device 003: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
   Bus 003 Device 002: ID 3938:1031  
   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   ```

My laptop is connected with LAN, and now i want to create a hotspot-
my laptop PCI wificard is not working, and I want to use external wificard(USB) to create the hotspot.

Could anyone please suggest how to use USB wificard to create the hotspot.

Answer (score 2):

In the `terminal`, type:

`sudo apt update` # update the software database

`sudo apt install dnsmasq-base` # install dnsmasq-base

`nm-connection-editor` # start the GUI editor

Click the + button to create a new connection... choose Wi-Fi...

[image]

Set up this window, including the MAC address of your USB dongle... if the USB dongle is currently inserted, you can just use the pull-down menu to enter the MAC address for you...

[image]

**Update #1:**

Set the `Band` to 2.4ghz, and the `Device` to the proper MAC address of the USB dongle (use the pop down menu to select).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done same thing but could not be able to connect. After seeting it up going to seetings and do "connect to hidden wifi" then select the driver and connection but this is not working

Comment: @SatishChandra If you're choosing "connect to hidden wifi" then you're not following my instructions. Please re-read the steps. Also, once the hotspot is running, you go to another computer, and connect to the hotspot wi-fi just like you do when you connect to any wi-fi network.

Comment: Hello sir, I follow the same instruction and did the same thing. I tried by just clicking the turn on wifi hotspot. after this when I was tring to connect the wifi from my mobile phone the wifi network only i can not see in my phone.

Comment: In the wifi setting I can see two driver(in two different tab) 1. AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI wifi adapter) 2. 802.11 n WLAN (USB) wifi driver. When I clicking the Turn On Wifi Hotspot even if from 2nd tab the hotspot is getting created and shows up in first tab, I think the hotspot is getting created by using PCI driver and not the USB one. and because the PCI driver is not working I can not see the network in my phone

Comment: @SatishChandra Please see Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: @SatishChandra please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!